# How do I customize Emacs compile output parsing?

Tags: emacs, xemacs

My current compile output is not being properly parsed in the *compilation* buffer.  How can I fix this?

Comment: More details please? What do you compile, what do you expect in the buffer and what is happening instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you'll have to modify the variable `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.  See the variable documentation by doing:

```
C-h v compilation-error-regexp-alist
```

or the info page:

```
C-h S compilation-error-regexp-alist
```